# Checkbox to make billing information same as shipping information does not work for Anonymous users

Tags: ajax, commerce

For Anonymous users, the **My Shipping information is the same as my Billing information** checkbox doesn't reload the Shipping Information checkout pane.

I have the checkbox working for authenticated users, but when an anonymous user is going through checkout, the ajax callback never fires. The `#element_validate` function `'commerce_customer_profile_copy_validate'` is never called. The `#ajax['callback'] => 'commerce_customer_profile_copy_refresh'` is never called.

Watching the network tab in Chrome, the ajax request is never fired.

The checkbox is checked by default and nothing happens when I un-check it. The Shipping Information pane doesn't expand and show the shipping information form fields via ajax.

Is there some permission I'm missing that would allow anonymous users to use this checkbox?

Comment: it certainly sounds like a permission issue but AFAIK there isn't any permission attached to AJAX. Have you tried emptying cache and rebuilding permissions to flush the error out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was kicking myself on this one. I forgot I had some custom `hook_js_alter` code in my `template.php` that removes unnecessary js from the page for anonymous users. This was done to improve site speed and because my custom theme didn't require these default Drupal js libraries.

```
function theme_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  $logged_in_user = user_uid_optional_load();
  if(!in_array("authenticated user", $logged_in_user->roles)) {
    foreach($javascript as $key => $value) {
      unset($javascript[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

However I do need these javascripts on commerce checkout pages apparently, so I added a `request_path()` check for `checkout` and `cart` pages so the js would not be `unset`.

I confirmed the **My Shipping information is the same as my Billing information** checkbox now works for anonymous users.